# Bohek CustomCS callback failed

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I am using Bokeh to do a dashboard and I would like to create a confirm button when user press on the confirm button, the saveButton will appear. The disabled property of saveButton will change from true to false. I have tried it with the following code and it seems like I have made something wrong. Should I pass the button arguments to Javascript? I am not very familiar with javascript. Thank you for your help

```
confirmButton = Button(label="Confirm Your Change", button_type="success")

callback = """
if (confirm("Confirm Saving?")) {
    saveButton.disabled = false;}

""" 
confirmButton.js_on_event(ButtonClick, CustomJS(code=callback))

saveButton = Button(label="Save", button_type="success",disabled=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to activate the `saveButton` by one click (and this stays activated afterwards), simply create the two Buttons, use `js_on_click()` and pass as an argument the second button. Then you can set the `disabled` value to `false`.

```python
confirmButton = Button(label="Confirm Your Change", button_type="success")
saveButton = Button(label="Save", button_type="success",disabled=True)
confirmButton.js_on_click(
    CustomJS(
        args=dict(saveButton = saveButton), 
        code="saveButton.disabled = false"
    )
)
```

If you want to toggle the status, use

```
code="saveButton.disabled = !saveButton.disabled"
```

inside the `CustomJS` function.